# Angular 6 -> 7 Routing and Lifecycle Hooks Issue

Tags: angular

Since we have updated our Angular version from 6 to 7, we have a small problem. After we click on a button, which navigate us to another path:

```
this.router.navigate(['xxx']);
```

On the other side, we have some initialization logic for our html, like scroll to top. And this does not work anymore with the newer version. When we debug, we see that the problem is this order:

Angular 6:

1. this.router.navigate
2. The targetted html will be rendered (You see immediately the next page)
3. The lifecycle hooks are called (ngOnInit which scrolls)

Angular 7:

1. this.router.navigate
2. The lifecycle hooks are called (ngOnInit, even ngAfterViewChecked)
3. And then the targetted html will be rendered

Is this a deserved behaviour / change on the newer version?
So where should i run our initialization logic now with Angular 7?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, was not able to understand why it was happening but i solved it by creating a directive and using that directive in html at the element where i want to scroll it after landing on that page or page refresh-

```js
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[sxScrollTo]'
})
export class ScrollToDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }

}
```

```html
<div sxScrollTo>
// html code
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried. unfortunately the same behaviour. I see my page after the ScrollToDirective is called.. strange

Answer (score 0):

As i workaround, i found this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

From Angular Doc:

> 'enabled'--restores the previous scroll position on backward
>   navigation, else sets the position to the anchor if one is provided,
>   or sets the scroll position to [0, 0] (forward navigation). This
>   option will be the default in the future.

This solved our current problem. But i still do not know why Angular 7 behaves strange regarding lifecycle hooks.